# Removing documents while preserving at least one

Tags: scala, mongodb, casbah

I have a MongoDB collection containing history data with id and timestamp.

I want to delete data from the collection older than a specific
timestamp. But for every id at least one
  document (the newest) must stay in the collection.

Suppose I have the following documents in my collection ...

```
{"id" : "11", "timestamp" : ISODate("2011-09-09T10:27:34.785Z")} //1
{"id" : "11", "timestamp" : ISODate("2011-09-08T10:27:34.785Z")} //2

{"id" : "22", "timestamp" : ISODate("2011-09-05T10:27:34.785Z")} //3
{"id" : "22", "timestamp" : ISODate("2011-09-01T10:27:34.785Z")} //4
```

... and I want to delete documents having a timestamp older than
2011-09-07 then
  1 and 2 should not be deleted because they are newer.
  4 should be deleted because it is older, but 3 should not be deleted
(although it is older) because
  at least one document per id should stay in the collection.

Does anyone know how I can do this with casbah and/or on the mongo
console?

Regards,
  Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a couple of ways. First, try this:

```
var cutoff = new ISODate("2011-09-07T00:00:00.000Z");
db.testdata.find().forEach(function(data) {
    if (data.timestamp.valueOf() < cutoff.valueOf()) {
        // A candidate for deletion
        if (db.testdata.find({"id": data.id, "timestamp": { $gt: data.timestamp }}).count() > 0) {
            db.testdata.remove({"_id" : data._id});
         }
    }
});
```

This does the job you want. Or you can use a MapReduce job to do it as well. Load this into a text file:

```
var map = function() {
    emit(this.id, {
        ref: this._id,
        timestamp: this.timestamp
    });
};


var reduce = function(key, values) {
    var cutoff = new ISODate("2011-09-07T00:00:00.000Z");
    var newest = null;
    var ref = null;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
        if (values[i].timestamp.valueOf() < cutoff.valueOf()) {
            // falls into the delete range
            if (ref == null) {
                ref = values[i].ref;
                newest = values[i].timestamp;
            } else if (values[i].timestamp.valueOf() > newest.valueOf()) {
                // This one is newer than the one we are currently saving.
                // delete ref
                db.testdata.remove({_id : ref});
                ref = values[i].ref;
                newest = values[i].timestamp;
            } else {
                // This one is older
                // delete values[i].ref
                db.testdata.remove({_id : values[i].ref});
            }
        } else if (ref == null) {
            ref = values[i].ref;
            newest = values[i].timestamp;
        }
    }
    return { ref: ref, timestamp: newest };
};
```

Load the above file into the shell: `load("file.js");`

Then run it: `db.testdata.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out: "results"});`

Then remove the mapReduce output: `db.results.drop();`